# Cannot upload image by PHP CURL to Cloudflare

Tags: php, curl, cloudflare

When I run the curl command below, I receive success response and the image can upload as normal:

```
curl -X POST -F file=@/myFolder/pic.png -H "Authorization: Bearer {tokenX}" https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/accounts/{accountX}/images/v1
```

But when I use PHP to exec curl by the code below:

```
// Generated by curl-to-PHP: http://incarnate.github.io/curl-to-php/
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/accounts/{accountX}/images/v1');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'file' => '@' .realpath('/myFolder/pic.png'));

$headers = array();
$headers[] = 'Authorization: Bearer {tokenX}';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
}
curl_close($ch);
```

Cloudflare return an error: `ERROR 9422: Decode error: image failed to be decoded: Uploaded image must have image/jpeg or image/png content type`

I run curl command and PHP code on the same local server.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Have a look at https://www.php.net/manual/en/curlfile.construct.php#refsect1-curlfile.construct-examples.

Comment: @UmairKhan Perfect! Your suggestion solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

echo json_decode(shell_exec('curl -X POST -F file=@./Rectangle36.png -H "Authorization: Bearer {{token}}" [https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/accounts/{{account}}/images/v1'](https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/accounts/%7B%7Baccount%7D%7D/images/v1%27)))->result->variants[0];

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).